# Get Rid of Duplicate Information in PHP

Tags: php

I am scraping a site, and it will scrape two address boxes - each of which may have minor differences.

One of the addresses is like this:

```
ONE MICROSOFT WAY
REDMOND WA 98052-6399
425-882-8080
```

And the other is like this:

```
ONE MICROSOFT WAY
REDMOND WA 98052-6399
```

I save the entire string for both (there's HTML tags around them in the original but I didn't think it was necessary to illustrate my point), and then separate based on those HTML tags. This means it processes each newline (i.e. ONE MICROSOFT WAY) as a separate variable.

What I want to do is to see if there are duplicates between the addresses, the problem is that they're separate values in the first array, and then in the internal array, it is separating each of the two addresses line by line.

So basically, is there a way to check for duplicate values?

Here is sample data:

```
<div class="mailer">
Mailing Address
<span class="mailerAddress">ONE MICROSOFT WAY</span>
<span class="mailerAddress">REDMOND WA 98052-6399</span>
<div class="mailer">
Business Address
<span class="mailerAddress">ONE MICROSOFT WAY</span>
<span class="mailerAddress">REDMOND WA 98052-6399</span>
<span class="mailerAddress">425-882-8080</span>
```

Comment: Well, in any case, this would require some programming work. What have you tried so far? What problems have you stumbled upon?

Comment: You can just check if one string exists in another one.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  Given the inputs you supplied above, what exactly is it that you need as the output(s)?  When you say duplicates, are you referring to duplicate lines, such as the "ONE MICROSOFT WAY" line and "REDMOND WA 98052-6399" line?  If so, wouldn't just a simple iteration-and-compare suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following method to clean data..
first, find the pattern, maybe like if the array A is `array('Hello', 'World')` and array B is `array('Hello World')` you can merge by saying `if(count(array) > 1) array = array[0] . ' ' .array[1]`
as for your case, lets say, each line is wrapped by HTML tags, but each line is stored within different array, am i wrong?

I would be glad if you can give sample data..
I'll use whatever for my sample code below...

```
<?
$sampleData = array(
  array('<p>ONE MICROSOFT WAY</p>', 'REDMOND'),
  array('<p>ONE MICROSOFT WAY</p>', 'REDMOND', 'Number')
);

foreach($data as $value) {
  unset($newKey);
  $newKey = trim(strip_tags($value[0])).trim(strip_tags($value[1]));
  $cleanData[$newKey] = $value;
}
?>
```

the point is, same keys will overwrite, ending up outputting unique keys (which stores unique values)...

another sample is that if you wanted to clear similar email address out of data stored in csv/array..

```
<?    
foreach($data as $value) {
  $cleanData[$value['email']] = $value;
}
?>
```

as simple as that.. `$cleanData` should now contain no data with similar email addresses..

Comment: um sorry for late response, so did you manage to do it? hence the check mark? or do I have to refine my answer based on your sample data? Though I still need to know what array 1 consists of and what array 2 consists of... (more like, the print_r output of the sample data)

Comment: I haven't managed to do it. Let me try print_r on the arrays.

Comment: I don't know how to display arrays fully as arrays in PHP - I did in Python (well, lists, they're called there)

Comment: Check out my `$sampleData` above, its array(data1, data2), and data1 consists of entry0 and entry1, data2 consists of entry0, entry1, entry2. What I need to know is the data structure, what kind of information is assigned to [0], [1], [2], etc.. and print_r shows it, without having you to manually type. here's print_r doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php